# Determine $X-Y$ offset for rotated element given the $Y$-offset without rotation

Tags: geometry

How to determine the $x$ and $y$ offset of an rotated element from which the $y$-offset without rotation is known?

**Example:**

[**Illustration of the problem**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEvj4.png)

The text in the example is pushed 2mm upwards when the rotation is 0. Ie `offsetY = -2`

- If the text would be rotated 90 degrees it is pushed to the right and
  I would want to get `offsetX=2` and `offsetY=0`.
- In the case of 180 degrees rotation the text would be pushed 2mm down instead of up, so I would get `offsetX=0` and `offsetY=2`.

**Desired solution**

I would need both the offsetX and offsetY to determine the new correct position and account for all degrees of rotation.

In mathematical terms:

```
offsetXafterRotation = ??
offsetYafterRotation = ??
```

Given the `RotationInDegrees` and `YoffsetWithoutRotation`.
I also have the `Width` and `Height` of the element.

Comment: You can't pose a SO question on math.SE and expect the conventions to be the same. Generally in mathematics, $y$ is considered to increase as we go 'upwards' and rotations are by default counterclockwise. You should be more specific. Also, how does width or height affect the answer? Aren't you asking about the rotation of just one point about another point?

Comment: I wasn't sure if the height and width would affect the answer, but I don't think so. The Y-offset is indeed about the center of rotation as in the answer you posted below. I will try your solution, at first glance it looks like it works. Sorry if I caused any problems.

Comment: No problems caused-- just some friendly advice to help you get a better response on any future questions you might pose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y$ be the initial vertical offset from the center of rotation. Let $x'$ and $y'$ be the offsets after rotation. Let $\theta$ be the angle through which the text is rotated *clockwise*.

$$x' = -y\cdot \sin \theta$$
$$y' = y\cdot \cos \theta$$

Comment: This was the solution. Can't believe it can be done so simplified. Thank you!!